# Focus stacking app for Android

Tags: android, camera

With my new Android phone, when I take a picture of my friend in front of a monument, either the friend or the monument are blurry.

I can take two pictures (tapping to focus on the friend then on the document), then perform [focus stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stacking) on desktop to have both sharp, but this is very inconvenient.

I would like an app that automatically/quickly takes several pictures at several focus distances (focus bracketing), then immediately starts stacking them into a sharp picture.

Bonus:

- Make the actual shooting as quick as possible (thus avoiding too much movement), prepare by checking what focus distances are necessary, possibly automatically or by letting the user tap on the important objects.
- Align pictures, as I usually do not carry a tripod.